# Change current element background in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<label class="default" for="checkbox1"><input id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" type="checkbox" style="display:none" /> some text</label><br />
<label class="default" for="checkbox2"><input id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" type="checkbox" style="display:none" /> some text</label><br />
<label class="default" for="checkbox3"><input id="checkbox3" name="checkbox3" type="checkbox" style="display:none" /> some text</label><br />
```

How should I change the currently clicked checkbox's label background color using jQuery? For example when the second checkbox is checked it's style should be changed with "checked":

```
<label class="checked" for="checkbox2"><input id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" type="checkbox" style="display:none" /> some text</label><br />
```

Comment: I'm sure this is a silly question, but if the checkboxes are set to display: none; then how are people clicking on them to check them in the first place?

Comment: Clicking on the label text will also check the checkbox...

Comment: so really we could assign the click event to the label itself, since the checkboxes are there simply for form data I presume.

Comment: Hey man, I noticed that you changed your example code based on my suggestion.  I'm still kind of new here, would it be rude of me to ask you to accept my answer?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a checkbox selector in jQuery, so using that, assign the click function to grab the parent "label" element and toggle the css class to "checked".  This will add the class and remove the class depending on the state of the checkbox.

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() { $(this).parent("label").toggleClass("checked");
```

Also, you will have more luck with your css class names if you do:

```
<label class="checked" for="checkbox2"><input id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" type="checkbox" style="display:none" /> some text</label><br />
```

instead of what you did above. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the `change` event and set the background color after checking whether `this.checked`.
For example:

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() { 
    $(this).css('background-color', this.checked ? 'red' : 'transparent');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[@type='checkbox']").click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('checked');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html should look more like this:

```
    <input id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" type="checkbox" style="display:none" />
<label style="default" for="checkbox1"> some text</label><br />
```

The jQuery will look like this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").select(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("checked");
});
```